# Should repeated downvotes without cause be treated as bullying?

Tags: discussion

Today we had repeated downvotes on one anwer to this question [How to lock object face a certain distance away from another object face?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17803/how-to-lock-object-face-a-certain-distance-away-from-another-object-face/17805#comment25082_17805)

Do we have a way to avoid this?

If I remember right this: [The NEW new "Be Nice" Policy ("Code of Conduct") — Updated with your feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback) appeared on Blender.SE in the 'Hot Meta Posts' box. Should users link to this posts and flag the post when this pattern appears again?.

Comment: Related: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/473/599 BTW, that proposal has been replaced by this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/238438

Comment: I believe they should. Unfortunately, we have no way to see if they were without cause. In the case brought up here JuhaW's answer was inadequate for the question, but the OP's receiving it acted unfairly. Rather than down-voting (thanks for the glares guys, it wasn't me) constructive comments should be added to alert that the answer or comment didn't reach criteria.

Comment: Note that the same user can't downvote repeatedly. Multiple downvotes means that multiple people all thought that the post was downvote worthy.

Comment: I'm not sure where all the concern over this is coming from all of a sudden, as we've had [lots of posts with downvotes before](http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?page=211&tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer).. And this is nothing compared to big sites like SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Voting (even downvoting) is a core part of the site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/), and is part of what makes SE what it is. Voting is important to separate the useful answers from the others.

## What makes a ["good", useful answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)?

This is obviously pretty subjective, and depends a lot on the type of question, context, and apparent skill level of the OP.

Users will vote based on their own opinions.

Obviously it's important that the answer has a explanation/solution which answers the OP's question, but aside from that, **IMO it's also important that the answer communicates the solution (and how to implement it) effectively**, especially if the OP is new.

A really nice answer might include instructions on how to do the various steps required, and perhaps an explanation of why it works (including this will help get upvotes too, as it gives users a good indication that the solution actually works, without having to test it themselves).

*These aren't supposed to be requirements or anything, just my own opinions of how a ideal answer might look.*

---

## When is it reasonable to downvote?

From the [help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/behavior):

> Above all, be honest. If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add
> comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong. Provide better
> answers of your own. Last but not least, edit and improve the existing
> questions and answers! By doing these things, you are helping keep
> Stack Exchange a great place to share knowledge of our craft.

[And](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down):

> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy,
> no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps
> dangerously incorrect.

Answers which don't satisfactorily answer or communicate an answer to the question (in some users opinion) will most likely be downvoted. **This isn't meant to be some sort of rude insult**, but an  impersonal indication that your answer could be improved.

**Simply put, don't take downvotes personally.**

---

Indeed, downvotes should absolutely ***never*** be used for insulting/being rude to a user.
If you see any rude/insulting comments, [flag them](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/flagging).
However, in the case of the post linked in the question, I don't see any evidence of this being the case.

Also remember that a single user cannot downvote a post multiple times, so even if a malicious user downvoted a post without good reason, it wouldn't amount to much. (a downvote is -2, compared to an upvote which is +10).

---

For more, meta.se has [*loads* of content on this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953/238438) (predictably ;))

### Writing detailed answers is time consuming. [Keep it friendly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), and don't take the votes *too* seriously

---

**Full disclosure:** *I was one of the downvoters on the post in question. I downvoted because I felt that the answer did not clearly explain how or why their answer worked.*
*I didn't write a comment, which was a failing on my part. I'll try to be more prompt with this in the future.*
*I've since retracted my vote, as the post was later edited to include more detail.*

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with your assumption that repeated down votes is bullying. Down voting is SE's way to filter content and bring the best answers up to the main view. There is no way that one person can down vote a answer multiple times. So I do not see how you can be calling it "bullying." If I or any other regular user wrote a bad answer, and it got down voted surely you would not call that bullying. As I said [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/489/2217)

> For a new user add a comment explaining what is wrong with their answer.

Some how thinking that down voting posts is bad goes against the very heart of SE and why this site works so well.
[**Why is voting important**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)

Don't misunderstand me, I did not down vote the answer in question. Nor do I have a vendetta against any of the users mentioned. I am simply trying to state that we can not take away down votes and have SE function as it is meant to.

Comment: To add my two cents, there has been a lot of traffic (more than the usual) around here lately so naturally, there will also be an increase in question views and votes.

Comment: I've noticed a lot of new traffic, too, and I'm concerned that "noobs" misunderstand the meaning of the downvote and take it as an insult, rather than a critique. Unrelated to the post in question, I have to admit, it's pretty frustrating when I've written what I believe to be a thorough, helpful answer, and I get a downvote with no comment. I don't mind the downvote so much as I mind not knowing how to improve.

Comment: @Matt very good point, and well said. I'm sure I will link to your comment at some point in the future.

Comment: Someone can go into your profile and down vote all your answers for no reason.

Comment: @LetTheWritersWrite While someone *"can"* go and rage DV all my posts, the votes would get reversed. SE can detect such things and all the votes would get changed by the next UTC 0000. But aside from all that, this was talking about mutipal vote on one post, not multiple vote from one person on many posts. That is a very big difference.

Comment: Someone dv three of my answers. It was obvious it was out of a grudge because they all happened back to back and yet SE wasn't smart enough to detect it.

Answer (score -1):

Well, there are many sites that are out-right-haywire-bonkers and for things to work well a site like this; it would have to be like an oasis away from the rest of the attitude seen elsewhere.

Otherwise it's contributing to the rest.  Everything is cumulative even if it's just a small thing like a down-vote.

(i) Someone may have just been called names and ridiculed by half a dozen people on game-dev.net.  People who never even bother to contribute at all, they just log in and cause trouble.

(ii) So this stressed out person now heads over to BA.org and see one of the moderators is again calling someone names and generally being rude to people and that many other people are also imitating this behavior so that most of the site is a verbal war-zone.

(iii) Next the person heads over here and sees multiple downvotes to an answer that he intended to be helpful but didn't realize that it fell short of help and actually look more like a hint.

I think a simple comment is far more helpful and since Up-votes leave incomplete answers at the bottom regardless.  Downvote's serve little functional benefit.

To sum up:

A: I feel DV's add to other problems people may encounter elsewhere and can easily be misinterpreted even if people are not supposed to take things personally.

A person can only take so much trouble online or at work;  Staying 100% stress-free is difficult even for the best of us.  Why should we add to that?

B: Up-votes filter the answers anyways so down-votes have no functional use.

A downside to downvotes-> It's too easy for down-votes to be misused as a substitute for rude gestures.
People often like to follow the crowd.

If there is down-voting taking place, then other people will follow along because they believe that this is the appropriate way to behave but do not understand WHY it is being used so they misuse it based on inexperience and likely grouchiness.

Just look at how many inexperienced people refer to themselves as 'Noobs', they are imitating each other.

To me it seems best to not give the crowds any behavior ideas that will catch on and be used in a context that we never intended.

We can certainly influence the masses of people into making down-voting a habitual behavior but we cannot control when and why they decide to down-vote,

Comment: Regarding point B, I don't agree. I think of votes with three possibilities: 1. upvote if the post is complete, understandable, answers question (if it's an answer). 2. don't vote if the post is incomplete or is somewhat unclear, but otherwise is promising (i.e. clearly had some effort put into it) 3. downvote if the post is incorrect or hard to parse, and has no apparent effort put into it. They also give users a way to reduce score on highly upvoted posts, that may not deserve it (in the user's opinion).

Comment: I was going to mention that downvotes can be used to keep a confusing or misleading post at zero.  I forgot.

Comment: Point B was a response to something David said about down-votes bringing bad answers to the bottom of the stack.  Upvotes do this anyways so down-votes are nor necessary for this to work.